# How do I use $location to to get the protocol host and port of my current url in a factory

Tags: angularjs, location, factory

How do I get the current protocol host and port of my current url?

```
app.factory('actionTypeFactory', ['$resource', function($resource, $location){
  return $resource($location.protocol() + '://'+ $location.host() +':'+  $location.port()  +'82/somelocation')
}]);
```

I would like the url to look like this:
   http:// localhost:80 /somelocation

Comment: I am getting an error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined

Comment: please update this as this will help other looking for answer. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must inject the $location service, that's why it is undefined:

```
app.factory('actionTypeFactory', ['$resource', '$location', function($resource, $location){
  return $resource($location.protocol() + '://'+ $location.host() +':'+  $location.port()  +'82/somelocation')
}]);
```

Comment: Why you don't just use `$location.absUrl()`?

Comment: You are right, but that was copypasta only to include the missing dependency @IslamWazery :)

Comment: Anyway, it's better to suggest it in you answer.

Comment: refer here for more information [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location]